# Connections have been added without my knowledge

Tags: windows, networking

I just got a clear wimaxx router and connected fine but after a couple of days i went to `ipconfig` it came back with connections I did not put it there.  Also why are all these other media devices on my laptop?

```
  Windows IP Configuration
   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : NBFIPS03
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : CARSONINC.LOCAL
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : CARSONINC.LOCAL
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 88-AE-1D-AC-03-2C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c4ed:bc3f:b55d:a1e7%35(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.15.172(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, September 01, 2011 10:41:41 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, September 02, 2011 10:41:42 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.15.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.15.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 847818269
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-14-6C-A9-37-88-AE-1D-AC-03-2C

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.15.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection* 22:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Check Point Virtual Network Adapter For SSL Network Extender
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 54-58-76-D0-84-1E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-27-10-40-F7-6D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6200 AGN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-27-10-40-F7-6C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Tunnel adapter isatap.{3DE91B76-0F29-4F66-9D0B-2E2829C1943F}:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:4137:9e76:34a5:3027:3f57:f053(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::34a5:3027:3f57:f053%33(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
Tunnel adapter isatap.{96E12E84-6E72-4ECE-80B3-4294474172FA}:
```

Comment: how do you know when you get an answer

Comment: you will be automatically notified by the indicator in the upper left part of the page (where it says Stack Exchange). You can also check the box to receive email responses for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Every possible connection type and its state is shown when you do `ipconfig`.

Your laptop has multiple ways to connect, including an Ethernet adapter, two wireless adapters, and a virtual interface. Only one is active.

Comment: only one is active when i am working from home when i am in the office others connect.  where did the dchp iaid come from and the preferred..

Comment: @chillibowl the tunnel connections could be used by your pc to connect to another network, where your work applications reside on. ex.vmware connections, SAP applications, citrix, etc